# Fitting Beta Distributions to Data

Tags: fitting, beta-distribution, scipy, numpy

I am trying to reproduce some beta distribution parameters found in this [published paper](https://www.cs.ucr.edu/~eamonn/Segmentation_ICDM.pdf). I have two data sets, `y1` and `y2`, that are generated in the following way (NumPy code):

```
size = 5000
x = np.arange(size)

# Dataset #1
I = np.random.randint(0, size, size=size)
k = I.shape[0]
nnmark = np.zeros(k)
y1 = np.zeros(k)

for i in range(k):
    j = I[i]
    nnmark[min(i, j)] = nnmark[min(i, j)] + 1
    nnmark[max(i, j)] = nnmark[max(i, j)] - 1

y1 = np.cumsum(nnmark)


# Dataset #2
I = np.empty(size, dtype=np.int)
for i in range(I.shape[0]):
    I[i] = np.random.randint(i, size)

for i in range(k):
    j = I[i]
    nnmark[min(i, j)] = nnmark[min(i, j)] + 1
    nnmark[max(i, j)] = nnmark[max(i, j)] - 1

y2 = np.cumsum(nnmark)
```

[image: Plotted Data]

`y1` is shown in black and `y2` is shown in red above. According to the paper, both curves can be approximated by a beta distribution. In the original paper, they claim that since `y1` has a width that is equal to the `size` and a height that is equal to `0.5*size` then this is a special case of the beta distribution with `beta(2, 2, a, c)`. Finally, their code shows that this any value from this distribution can be computed from:

```
y = 2*(x)*(size-z)/size
```

It isn't clear how this is derived. I am only familiar with basic beta distributions with alpha and beta parameters bounded between [0,1] and some references explain that `a` and `c` often refer to the `location` and `scale` of the distribution. I also noticed that the height of `y1` and `y2` are quite large and, unfortunately, I don't know how to create, fit, or rescale a beta distribution so as to obtain the correct parameters that would fit either of these curves.

My final goal would be to change the `size` (currently it is set to 5,000 for demonstration purposes but it can be smaller or larger) and be able to represent that dataset with an approximate beta distribution (albeit, it will likely need to be stretched horizontally and vertically).

I have been looking at the [SciPy beta distribution](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.beta.html) function but the documentation is vague. I've gotten as far as:

```
a1, b1, c1, d1 = beta.fit(y1, loc=0, scale=size)
a2, b2, c2, d2 = beta.fit(y2, loc=0, scale=size)
```

But neither of the PDFs look like the original data when plotted next to it.

Comment: The way you are using `scale` isn't correct. Try setting it to 1. `c1` and `d1` should be 0 or close to 0. Then try plotting `x = np.linspace(0, 1, 100); plt.plot(x, beta.pdf(x, a1, b1))`

Comment: According to the (vague) documentation, it looks like fit should use fscale and not scale. I believe that loc and scale are actually ignored. Additionally, in order to specify `floc` and `fscale` together one needs to take care and have `floc < x < floc+fscale` (so one might need to add/subtract a very small constant 1e-10 if x contains values that land right on the boundary limits). The x_range of my data is between [0, 5000] and the y_range is between [0, 2500] for y1 and it isn't clear if I need to normalize it first before fitting.

Comment: Ah, you are right, it is `fscale`. Is this a demonstration of what you are trying to do? https://gist.github.com/CamDavidsonPilon/c391527022ccae889f2ec04ac2e1e5cc

Comment: I think I realize what the problem is. `y1` and `y2` aren't "data". Instead, they are histograms that approximates some beta pdf. That is, I'm not drawing from a distribution and then fitting a beta distribution from the drawn data. Instead, what I am looking for is a way to fit a beta distribution to each histogram.

Comment: I am wondering if something like this where I can draw data samples from my histogram might be appropriate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54535378/2955541

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To generate an accurate curve fit, you can sample the histogram via the `scipy.stats.rv_histogram` function and then average over the fitted parameters from multiple iterations:

```
n_iter = 1000
params = np.empty((n_iter, 2))
for i in range(n_iter):    
    n_samples = 1000
    hist_dist = scipy.stats.rv_histogram((y2, np.append(np.arange(k), k)))
    data = hist_dist.rvs(size=n_samples)
    a, b, c, d = scipy.stats.beta.fit(data, floc=0, fscale=k)

    params[i, 0] = a
    params[i, 1] = b

a_mean = np.round(np.mean(params[:, 0]), 2)
b_mean = np.round(np.mean(params[:, 1]), 2)
print(a_mean, b_mean)

y2_normalized_fit = scipy.stats.beta.pdf(np.arange(k), a_mean, b_mean, loc=0, scale=k)
scaling_factor, _, _, _ = np.linalg.lstsq(y2_normalized_fit.reshape(-1,1), y2, rcond=None)
```

Then, you multiply the `scaling_factor` by the fitted curve to get the right curve.

```
y2_normalized_fit * scaling_factor
```

[image]